# Selecting multiple columns from a DataTable

Tags: c#

My code :

```
 ProductRangesForNewRowsDt = ProductRangesDt.Select("PRODUCT_NAME, MIN_QUANTITY, MAX_QUANTITY, COMISSION_TEMPLATE where PROVIDER_ID = " + PROVIDER_ID).CopyToDataTable();
```

where `ProductRangesForNewRowsDt` is a `DataTable` and `ProductRangesDt` is another `DataTable` that contains these columns:

```
PRODUCT_ID
PRODUCT_NAME
PROVIDER_ID.PROVIDER_NAME
MIN_QUANTITY
MAX_QUANTITY
COMISSION_TEMPLATE
```

I am getting this error :

> Syntax error in the expression.

Comment: You can use LINQ for this ..

Comment: can u give me an example plz ?

Comment: @Sora please provide more detailed code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DataTable.Select` returns an array of `DataRow` so providing that your columns exist in your `DataTable` then you will return all the columns in that row anyway.  The `.Select` is to be used with a `WHERE` clause so you can do something like this:

```
DataRow[] rows = ProductRangesDt.Select("PROVIDER_ID = " + PROVIDER_ID);
```

And then use whatever method you like to get those rows into your target data table.

To just get the columns you want, then you should derive a `DataView` from the data table, copy this to another data table and query this new set.

```
DataView view = new DataView(ProductRangesDt);
DataTable dtQueryTable = view.ToTable(false, new string[] { "PROVIDER_ID", "PRODUCT_NAME", "MIN_QUANTITY", "MAX_QUANTITY", "COMISSION_TEMPLATE" });

DataRow[] rows = dtQueryTable.Select("PROVIDER_ID = " + PROVIDER_ID);
```

Having just re-read this, you could also do it the other way. Query what you have, make a data table of your new filtered set, and then use a `DataView` to extract the columns you want.

**EDIT**

To get *only* the columns you want, try the other way

```
DataTable dtFiltered = ProductRangesDt.Select("PROVIDER_ID = " + PROVIDER_ID).CopyToDataTable();

DataView view = new DataView(dtFiltered);
DataTable dtSpecificCols = view.ToTable(false, new string[] { "PRODUCT_NAME", "MIN_QUANTITY", "MAX_QUANTITY", "COMISSION_TEMPLATE" });
```

*The above isn't tested, it's just a quick-shot reply.*

Comment: it's not what i want because your code return a row with all the column of the ProductRangesDt  i don't want that i just want the specified columns not all of them

Comment: @sora check the edit, although I personally think you need to re-look at how your trying to achieve this.

Comment: i figure out what u did there but still it's not what i want in your code rows still contain the PROVIDER_ID and i don't want that

Comment: @sora in that case, try doing it the other way like I've suggested. Query your set as-is, then create a `DataView` from this set with only the columns you want and create your data table from this view.